# android table layout top margin

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TableLayout
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="0.95"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_1"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.1dp"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="hell wolrd"
            android:inputType="text"

            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_2"
            android:layout_weight="0.55"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.1dp"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="hell wolrd"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_3"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.1dp"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            ></Spinner>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_4"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.1dp"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my xml file which shows the following result.

[image]

But when I run the code, the screen displays this:
The second edit text is giving problem. Kindly if anyone can help
What could be the possible reason? 
Is this margin?
Why it is happening when I am not changing anything in the Class file.

[image]

Comment: Have you check your theme style you are using? Try to set margin="0" and padding="0" in your theme in style

Comment: No effect. The problem lies somewhere else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

in EditText(et_2) to

```
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```